# How to match a Linux driver with a hardware device

Tags: linux, module

I am writing a Linux driver for some custom hardware. My questions is how does Linux match the hardware to my driver. The hardware's DT entry is

```
nvme_host_sys@43c00000 {
        clock-names = "sys_clk_p", "sys_clk_n", "aclk";
        clocks = <0x13 0x13 0x13>;
        compatible = "xlnx,nvme-host-sys-1.0";
        interrupt-names = "intr";
        interrupt-parent = <0x4>;
        interrupts = <0x0 0x1d 0x4>;
        reg = <0x43c00000 0x80000>;
        phandle = <0x38>;
    };
```

I can insert my driver using modprobe and that works fine as I can see the printk in the init being written. I can also create an entry in /dev using mknod and that also works fine. But is the driver now associated with the hardware? Do I need to do something else? Thanks

Comment: It does so via the major and minor devices numbers the kernel has assigned to the hardware, and that you've registered in your driver.

Comment: how does the kernel decide which major and minor device numbers to assign to hardware?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In the driver code we just need to add the following :-

```
static struct of_device_id nvmedrv_of_match[] = {
    { .compatible = "xlnx,nvme-host-sys-1.0", },
    { /* end of list */ },
};
```